# Compilation failed in R.java

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am facing this issue

> already predefined class in java public static final int Scam Guide=0x7f0c0081;

This error occurred in the R.java class.
I don't how to solve this.

```
   public static final class id {
    public static final int Scam Guide=0x7f0c0081;
    public static final int action0=0x7f0c0094;
    public static final int action_bar=0x7f0c0060;
    public static final int action_bar_activity_content=0x7f0c0000;
    public static final int action_bar_container=0x7f0c005f;
    public static final int action_bar_root=0x7f0c005b;
}
```

when running the app, the following error messages are shown.

```
/home/senm-01/dev/git-repos/scamlook_android/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com/sem/scamlookup/R.java
Error:(2619, 37) error: ';' expected
Error:(2619, 43) error: <identifier> expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

I don't know why this error occurred and the gradle build also failed.
How to solve this error?

Comment: Try to clean project, then run your app again, not very sure but it may fix your problem.

Comment: I cleaned my project many times

Comment: You have a typo in your resources. ID values cannot contain spaces.

Comment: I edited the space and when i run it the error is shown again with a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search your project XML files for

```
android:id="@+id/Scam Guide"
```

And remove the space

Then clean and rebuild the project

Comment: Ok ,i will make a search

Comment: Tkhs a lot @ cricket_007, when i searched it id value in xml value is error

Comment: Okay, so you can fix it?

Comment: I fixed it now.

Comment: No, if you're question shows research effort and is clear, then up vote. If you'd known that you cannot edit R.java and you would have known that it comes from XML sources, then you might not have asked the question